# Pass array of arrays (or slice of slices) in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I need to pass a reference to an array of references to arrays (or slice of slices) to the following function in Rust

```
const LNGTH: usize = 5;

fn swap_array<T>(x: &mut [&[T; LNGTH]]) {
    let temp = x[1];
    x[1] = x[0];
    x[0] = temp;
}
```

The problem is that it seems I have to specify an array length for the "inner" arrays (here: `LNGTH`).

So, the following code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x_array: [i32; LNGTH] = [5,2,8,9,1];
    let x_other: [i32; LNGTH] = [6,7,6,7,6];        
    let mut y_array: [&[i32; LNGTH]; 2] = [&x_array, &x_other];
    println!("before : {:?}", y_array);
    swap_array(&mut y_array);
    println!("after  : {:?}", y_array);    
}
```

But if I change the signature of `swap_array` to `fn swap_array<T>(x: &mut [&[T]])`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:16
   |
14 |     swap_array(&mut y_array[..]);
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found array of 5 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut [&[_]]`
              found type `&mut [&[i32; 5]]`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: Could not compile `tut_arrays`.
```

From the perspective of C, I would like to have a function that accepts arguments of type `T**`. A corresponding function in C would look like that

```
void swap_arrays(my_type ** x) {
    my_type* temp = x[1];
    x[1] = x[0];
    x[0] = temp;
}
```

Comment: _"But if I change the signature of swap_array to `fn swap_array<T>(x: &mut [&[T; LNGTH]])`"_ — that's what it already is. Did you mean to say `fn swap_array<T>(x: &mut [&[T]])`?

Comment: @PeterHall Thank you for pointing out to this typo. I fixed it now.

Comment: Note that in C the situation is similar: a two dimensional array `int x[5][10]` is not convertible to `int**` but to `int (*)[10]`.

Comment: Thanks, @rodrigo. Your comment is very elucidating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slice-of-slices version:

```
const LEN: usize = 5;

fn swap_array<T>(x: &mut [&[T]]) {
    let temp = x[1];
    x[1] = x[0];
    x[0] = temp;
}

fn main() {
    let x_array: [i32; LEN] = [5, 2, 8, 9, 1];
    let x_other: [i32; LEN] = [6, 7, 6, 7, 6];
    let mut y_array: [&[i32]; 2] = [&x_array, &x_other];
    println!("before : {:?}", y_array);
    swap_array(&mut y_array);
    println!("after  : {:?}", y_array);
}
```

You have to change the formal argument to slice of slices, and the elements of `y_array` must be slices, too (the latter is basically what the error message said).